# ¿Como hacer visible el texto de un JPasswordField en java?

Tags: java

he estado investigando sobre como podria tener una vista previa de la clave ingresada en un jPasswordField al presionar un JButton. Pero resulta que no encuentro nada.

Me podrian decir si se puede, y si se puede, ¿Como se hace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar el método [setEchoChar()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#setEchoChar(char)). Pasando el valor 0 indicas que quieres ver el JPasswordField como si fuera un JTextField

`setEchoChar((char)0);`

Comment: Efectivamente! Gracias por tu colaboración, me ha funcionado perfectamente!

Comment: me alegro, saludos.

Comment: como funcionaria de forma inversa?

Comment: @DamianAguirre `setEchoChar('*')` para mostrar asteriscos de nuevo